# Django ModelForm initial or custom field value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a simple model and even simpler model form, but I just can't figure it out how to set initial, or custom value to my form field.

I tried with `form.cleaned_data['fieldname'] = value, initial={'field':value}, form.fields['field'].initial = value`, even indexing it like this `form.cleaned_data['status'] = Locked.STATUS[0][0]` but I couldn't make it work.

For the record, I want to use choice field from my model. The field name is 'STATUS', and I want to set first value('odlozen') to be used as a form field value, in my views.py. So form.cleaned_data needs to be STATUS value of 'odlozen', when this function triggers.

*PS. Don't mind me for not declaring my whole code, since it not necessary for this question. Thanks!*

Lets start with my code :

models.py

```
class Locked(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('odlozen', 'Odložen'),    #this is the value
        ('u_procesu', 'U procesu'),
        ('ne_javlja_se', 'Ne javlja se'),
        ('zakazan', 'Zakazan'),
        ('odustao', 'Odustao'),
        ('default', 'Izaberite status.'),
    )
    ...
    opp_comment = models.CharField(max_length=155, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS, blank=True)    #I set blank=True for no reason, it can be False also. 
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Locked'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Locked'
        get_latest_by = 'locked_name'

    def __str__(self):
        return smart_str(self.locked_eluid)
```

This is my forms.py :

```
class OppDetaljiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Locked

        fields = [... ,'status','opp_comment', ...]
        labels = {
            ...
            'opp_comment': 'Comment',
            'status': 'Status',
            ...
        }
        widgets = {
            ...
            'status': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'opp_comment': forms.Textarea()

        }
```

My view.py :

```
def odlozi(request, pk):
    opp_locked = Locked.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = OppDetaljiForm(instance=opp_locked)
    ...

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OppDetaljiForm(request.POST or None, instance=opp_locked, initial={'status': 'odlozen'})

        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data['status'] = 'odlozen'    #?! As I said before, none of my ideas worked.
            ...
            form.save()
            ...

            return redirect('appname:url')    # Dont mind me for not declaring my code, since it not necessary
    context = {
        'form': form,
        ...
    }
    return render(request, 'myhtmlpage.html', context)
```

And this is the HTML :

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row my-4">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                    {{ form.status|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
                    {{ form.opp_comment|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                ...
                   # Other form fields    
                ...
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-light" href="{% url 'appname:url' %}">Back</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few ways:

- If in your model you set a default value, afaik it will be used as initial value in the corresponding `ModelForm`
- Or just pass an `initial` dictionary to the form's initialiser:

  ```
  form = OppDetaljiForm(instance=opp_locked, initial={'status': 'odlozen'})
  ```

Note however that since you're passing an instance (`opp_locked`), the value taken from the instance supersedes the value from `initial`.

The **initial** value you're talking about is the value of the field shown to the user in the form when the user hasn't selected anything to start with. That's different than **overriding** the value *after* the user submits the form (ignoring the user input). You can do that in the form's clean method for the field:

```
# in OppDetaljiForm
def clean_status(self):
    status = self.cleaned_data.get('status')
    if not status:
        status = 'odlozen'
    return status
```

Finally, if the user cannot set the `status` anyway, then don't put it in the form at all (remove it from `fields` and from your template altogether) and set it in your view before saving the model:

```
if form.is_valid():
    opp_detail = form.save(commit=False)  # gives you the instance without saving it
    opp_detail.status = 'odlozen'  # add values that your form didn't set
    opp_detail.save()  # now save
```

Or let the form handle it:

```
class OppDetaljiForm(forms.ModelForm):
     status = 'odlozen'
     class Meta:
         fields = (<list of fields without 'status'!>)
     # ...
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.instance.status = self.status  # assigns the status to the instance
```

You say you have six forms, if the only difference is which status they set, then just make one form and pass the status to the init method so in your view you can do `form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=..., status='odlozen')` for example.

Comment: Hmm, that might be the problem... What can I do than? Remove the instance, or change it?

Comment: Ok, you'll have to explain better what you want. You're letting the user select the value (since it's one of the fields in the form) but you don't want that and you want to set it to some other value before saving?

Comment: I just updated my code. I have 6 other forms and 6 other functions, each one has to have one of the given statuses. This one, needs to have status == 'odlozen' which will be setted automatically when the user sends back the form. But as we can see, form field in the html is hidden, so it needs to be filled from the function.

Comment: And the value from opp_locked needs to be 'odlozen' sice the form is meant to update the model itself

Comment: Updated my answer. Again, don't add the hidden input field. It just doesn't make sense. Also anyone can change the values from hidden input fields if they want to anyway, so that's never a good way to set values (unless it's not important).

Comment: Actually, I don't know how could I forgot that I can simply remove it from the form and handle it in the model logic as you said. Thank you for the detailed question, It helped me.